# Trying to run hello world JavaScript program on visual studio but keep getting 'document' is undefined

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

[image: Error that I am getting and my simple code]

I've watched videos and when people run this it works just fine. I also tried console.log and I get-- 'console' undefined. I have node.js installed

Comment: `document.log` doesn’t exist anywhere. Did you mean `console.log`?

Comment: document is a variable in browsers, your console likely does not have it. In the browser the `log` function commonly used is `console.log`.

Comment: isn't document an object?

Comment: @IsaiahCanales — *in browsers* ,`document` is a variable to which an object is assigned.

Answer (score 1):

`document` is not a built-in part of JavaScript. It is part of the Web API provided by browsers which you get when you load your JS by using a `<script>` element in an HTML document in a web browser. You aren't doing that, and `document` doesn't have a `log` method anyway.

You're running your JS using Windows Script Host, which isn't that. WSH does not have a `document`.

You probably want either:

- the [`WriteLine` method](https://admhelp.microfocus.com/uft/en/all/VBScript/Content/html/0b1a80c3-7115-4643-a83f-7679659885b5.htm)
- to not use WSH (Browsers and Node.js being more common ways to run JS)

Comment: I tried console.log and get 'console' is undefined

Comment: @IsaiahCanales – WSH doesn't have `console` either.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't running in a browser, there is no `document` (plus, it'd be `console.log` there too). You are running in Windows Script Host, you can use `WScript.Echo` instead. But I'd rather recommend you to run your code in a browser or node.js anyway, WSH isn't a very useful environment for learning modern JavaScript.

You wrote you have node.js installed, so the issue could be that you simply used the wrong command: it should be `node` and not `start`!

Comment: How do I configure it to run in a browser?

Comment: Put a script tag inside of an HTML page that loads your script and open the page in your browser.

Comment: so node.js is to test programs on server side?

Comment: No. Node.js is to run JS. There are many applications for JS outside the browser. Some of them involve server-side programming. Some of them involve testing. Some of them involve other things.

Comment: oh okay, always thought javascript was just used to bring websites to life.